# Clearing toggle state

Tags: jquery

I have a form select replacement that uses jQuery to show options in a UL list when a user clicks a link. Clicking on an option changes a hidden form value and hides the list. Everything works fine, but if the user clicks somewhere outside the list or image I would like for the list to hide. It looks like I need to clear the toggle state and hide the list, but I haven't been able to do that. (Inspired by delicious.com multi-option search.)

```
$('ul.left').hide();

$('ul.downarrow li a').click(function(){
  $('ul.left').toggle();
});

$('ul.left li a').click(function() { 
  $('ul.left').hide();
  $('#sitesearchquery').val($(this).attr('name'));        
});

<ul class="downarrow">
  <li><a style="cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; width:20px; height:20px; background: url(images/down_arrow.gif);"></a>
    <ul class="left">
      <li><a href="#" name="mysite">My Site</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" name="othersite">Other Site</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
...
<input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" id="sitesearchquery" value="mysite" />
```

Comment: I havent got access to test this yet but just checking out jquery not selector, could you do $(':not(ul.left:child)').click(function(){$('ul.left').hide();})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event bubbling to do what you want, like this:

```
$('ul.downarrow').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); //stop event from bubbling
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('ul.left').hide();
});
```

When a `click` bubbles to `document` (normal bubble behavior), we hide `ul.left`.  When you click *inside* that `<ul>`, you can just prevent that bubble from happening using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)...so clicking anywhere outside the `<ul>` causes it to hide, anywhere inside has no additional effects  :)

Answer (score 0):

A plugin designed for your usecase:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/